# How to trigger GitHub actions on push of current branch?

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have  created the following GitHub Actions workflow.

```
name: Testing CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ my-branch ]
```

Here in `branches: [my-branch]` I am putting the name of the current branch.

But I want the workflow file to automatically take the name of the current branch.

Is there a parameter I can pass `branches: [my-branch]` here to automatically take the branch name?

Comment: did u try with variable **GITHUB_REF**?

Comment: yes I tried like this---> branches: ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/} this, but it was not working.

Comment: @manishsoni Hence my recommendation to use a dedicated GitHub Action (https://github.com/EthanSK/git-branch-name-action) in my answer below.

Comment: okay got it @VonC

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify a branch name, then, in order for your action to run on push for all branches: `on: [push]`

Then you can use [`EthanSK/git-branch-name-action`](https://github.com/EthanSK/git-branch-name-action) in order to get the current branch name.

That action uses [`process.env.GITHUB_REF`](https://github.com/EthanSK/git-branch-name-action/blob/46911153dd91b180a2af917d2412f0f29e026dc0/index.js#L9-L17),
and is the equivalent of [this solution](http://export%20GIT_BRANCH=$(echo%20$%7BGITHUB_REF:-dev%7D%20%7C%20sed%20s/.*%5C%5C///g)):
`export GIT_BRANCH=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF:-dev} | sed s/.*\\///g)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this And it will run on push of any branch:

```
on: [push]
```